# Django: Model query extract not looping in template

Tags: django, django-template-filters

So, I'm making this app in django and using this code:

My template tag in video_select.py file:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def content_list():
    contentlist = vvideo.objects.all()
    return contentlist
```

My template:

```
{% load video_select %}
<article id="menu" style="height:80%;">
    <h2 class="major">Menu</h2>
    <div>
        {% for contentt in content_list %} {{ contentt.video_path }} {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <h2 class="major">End Menu</h2>
</article>
```

This displays nothing. But I'm not sure why.

Conversely, simply printing out {% content_list %} does print out this output:

```
[<vvideo: vvideo object>, <vvideo: vvideo object>, <vvideo: vvideo object>, <vvideo: vvideo object>, <vvideo: vvideo object>, <vvideo: vvideo object>]
```

So clearly the template tag is working. My models.py contains:

```
class vvideo(models.Model):
    video_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

so, clearly the .video_path reference is also correct.

Can you help me understand why my list isn't looping & printing out? I tried iterating it directly in the template tag and it is working. However, I really want the loop to run in the template itself because I am trying to create href links for each video. So, I need to loop through all videos in the database and extract their names and urls, creating respective links. That's two items required for each line output: therefore, it's probably better to send a list of objects to the template and have it extract url and names of the videos in a loop.

Comment: is there a chance that all your video_path values are blank?  I'd try {{contentt.id}} and see if you get anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have to call the template tag and assign it to a variable before you can use it, you can't just reference it as if it was itself a variable.

```
{% content_list as my_content %}
{% for contentt in my_content %} {{ contentt.video_path }} {% endfor %}
```